# Visual Studio 2013 não instala no windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, instalador

Eu não consigo instalar o Visual Studio 2013 no Windows 7, sei que é possível pois na faculdade temos o Visual Studio instalados no Windows 7. Então não sei porque ele reclama da versão do Windows.

[image: SS]

Comment: Você tem todas atualizações do Windows 7? Por exemplo o Windows 7 Service Pack 1? Ele é original? Você clicou no *link*? O que diz?

Comment: A julgar pela versão do Internet Explorer estar desatualizada, parece que seu sistema operacional realmente não possui todas as atualizações instaladas. Além dos riscos óbvios de segurança, isso pode ser a causa do seu problema, como o colega @bigown falou.

Comment: @William, você pode aceitar então a resposta dada pelo bigown, já que ela parece ter sido a solução para seu problema?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Muito provavelmente está faltando o *Service Pack 1* no *Windows 7*, ou pode ser outra atualização dele. Tem que ter certeza que está tudo atualizado. Veja no *link* apresentado mais detalhes se isto não for o problema, mas provavelmente é.

Ele também fala em atualizar o IE, já para o 11. Não deixa uma máquina com coisas antigas deste jeito.

[Requerimentos](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-system-requirements-vs.aspx#30).

Comment: Vocês são os melhores, segui as dicas de vocês e consegui instalar o Visual Studio, era só instalar o service pack 1 do windows 7. Valeu galera!

Comment: @WilliamCaetano por favor marque a resposta como correta, isso pode ajudar outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. +1

Answer (score 0):

Habilite o Windows Update com certeza o problema é esse para ativar o Windows Upadate no Windows 7 caso não saiba:

> Painel de Controle > Windows Update > Alterar configurações > Instalar
>   atualizações automaticamente (recomendado).

Answer (score 0):

Atualize o IE para 10 ou 11(dependendo o que for pedido pela instalação).
Pois já passei por isso, e quando atualizei o IE.
Deu certo.